# Change the datatype of a column in a partitioned table with billion rows

Tags: oracle

We have a table with 120 partitions on date range which in turn is subpartitioned again on range.

Each partition has around 200 million records, the conventional way of changing the datatype will make our production unresponsive for hours.Is there any better way for changing the datatype of such a huge table?

We have already tried the following options:

1. Exchange partition. This does not work.
2. Create a new table with the same structure as the existing one and the altered column, and inserting the data using /*+ append *. It again takes hours.

Currently the column size is varchar2(30). We need to change it to:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS MODIFY (INFO VARCHAR2(50) );
```

Comment: If you are just worried about how long production is unresponsive (as opposed to how long the operation takes), you could use `dbms_redefinition`.  That'll take at least as long as creating the new table, it just won't stop ongoing operations while it's running

Comment: Making a varchar2() field larger is a meta data change and doesn't change the underlying data. Ref: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:8753545300346585555

Comment: @JustinCave, for dbms_redefinition you need (temporary) double amount of disc space - might be an issue for such a big table.

Comment: Changing `varchar2(30)` to `varchar2(50)` should work instantly and should not cause any trouble.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - please make that an answer.You're absolutely correct - expanding the size of a VARCHAR2 field is "just" a matter of updating the column definition in the system tables. No changes to the data are required. Now, if you were *shrinking* the column or it was defined as CHAR all bets are off, but as you're expanding a VARCHAR2 field you should be golden. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `varchar2(30)` to `varchar2(50)` should work instantly and should not cause any trouble.

You modify just some meta data but actual table data is not touched.

Comment: This does not work instantly, we have already tried that, it took hours. Then we had to stop, which again took a long time to rollback.

Comment: Perhaps the table is locked because your application writes data into this table all the time. Pause the applications, alter the column (should take only a few seconds) and start application again.

Comment: Looks like that was exactly the issue. We turned off all the applications, and it worked. This should have been my first check, silly me *Covering face with hands*. Thanks you so much!